# Extension, InViewerSearch

Tags: autodesk-viewer

We want to add our viewer extension: Autodesk.InViewerSearch

I have done the steps indicated in the link:

https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/tutorials/in-viewer-search-ext/
 The declaration of the variable config3d:

```
var config3d = {
extensions: ['MyBotonesExtension', 'Autodesk.InViewerSearch']
}

config3d.inViewerSearchConfig = {
        searchDefaultText: "",
        uiEnabled: true,
        clientId: 'adsk.viewer.defaultClientId',
        sessionId: 'adsk.viewer.defaultSessionId',

    relatedItemsTab:{
        enabled: true,  //if false we hide the tab
        displayName: 'This Item',
        pageSize: 20
    },
    loadedModelTab: {
        enabled: true,  //if false we hide the tab
        displayName: 'This View',
        pageSize: 50
    }

};

viewerApp.registerViewer(viewerApp.k3D, Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D, config3d);
```

In my index.html:

```
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/Extension-InViewerSearch.js"></script>
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/viewer3D.min.js?v=2.11.*"></script>
```

Extension-InViewerSearch.js->

https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers-dev/latest/docs/extensions_InviewerSearch_InViewerSearchExtension.js.html

ERROR:

```
typeError: n[m] is undefined


i.initSharedPropertyDatabase()    viewer3D.min.js:38
i.initCurrentPropertyDatabase()   viewer3D.min.js:38
i.getCurrentGeometryAttributes()  viewer3D.min.js:38
f/h.initializeAllAttributes()     viewer3D.min.js:38
j.InViewerSearchThisView.prototype.initialize()  viewer3D.min.js:38
a() viewer3D.min.js:36
h/p() viewer3D.min.js:36
f/<()
```

I change viewer3d.min.js by viewer3d.js

ERROR IN viewer3D.js:

```
 typeError: geometriesFlat[current] is undefined


 proto.initSharedPropertyDatabase() viewer3D.js:89706
 proto.initCurrentPropertyDatabase() viewer3D.js:89724
 proto.getCurrentGeometryAttributes() viewer3D.js:89778
 Controller/ctrl.initializeAllAttributes() viewer3D.js:88945
 viewerSearchNameSpace.InViewerSearchThisView.prototype.initialize()   viewer3D.js:88260
initializeSearchTabs() viewer3D.js:85412
initialize/onGetGeometriesDone() viewer3D.js:85603
getGeometries/<()
```

I made another extension running development differently, when the geometry is loaded and ... the result has been the same ... same error:

```
 viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT,
                function (event) {


                    var options = {
                        searchDefaultText: "",
                        uiEnabled: true,
                        clientId: 'adsk.viewer.defaultClientId',
                        sessionId: 'adsk.viewer.defaultSessionId',
                        thresholdSearchMaxNodes: 50000,

                        loadedModelTab: {
                            enabled: true,
                            displayName: 'This View',
                            pageSize: 50
                        },

                        relatedItemsTab: {
                            enabled: true,
                            displayName: 'This Item',
                            pageSize: 20
                        }
                    };
                    viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.InViewerSearch", options);
```

In the display only shows the magnifying glass icon.

I hope to hear from somebody soon...

Thank you so much

Comment: I don't have the issue in my application, I have a thin wrapper around the InViewerSearch extension:
https://github.com/Developer-Autodesk/library-javascript-viewer-extensions/blob/master/src/Viewing.Extension.InViewerSearch/Viewing.Extension.InViewerSearch.js
Then I am using A360ViewingApplication, so I can switch between views from the UI:
https://github.com/leefsmp/LMV-React/blob/master/src/shared/Components/ViewerPage/ViewerPage.js#L185
But it was working fine also with the standard viewing application.

Comment: A live demo is running here:
https://react-gallery.autodesk.io/viewer?id=58176294f352ff840fa53078&extIds=Viewing.Extension.InViewerSearchWrapper
Hope that helps ...

Comment: Is it specific to a model or you can reproduce with any model?

Comment: Gracias @PhilippeLeefsma, 
It is to load any model.
I also use Autodesk360ViewingApplication.
 ViewerApp = new Autodesk.A360ViewingApplication ( 'MyViewerDiv'); http://pruebaextensiones.azurewebsites.net/?ID=1

Comment: Hi, I created a very simple sample to test this extension. It looks working well at my side. I did not explicitly  enclose Extension-InViewerSearch.js. Viewer3D loaded the relevant codes automatically. So at the beginning when the viewer UI is ready, it took a few seconds to see the Search button is enabled. My sample is available at: http://a360.co/2fWcOsG . to run it, replace your credentials at ForgeRoute.js and your model urn at TestMain.js Hope it could help your to address the issue at your side.

Comment: Hello Xiaodong Liang
Thanks for your help, I found the problem.

When I load the document:
I give a parameter view I want to show.

viewerApp.loadDocumentWithItemAndObject (documentId, "{3D}").

So InViewerSearch not work for me.

viewerApp.loadDocumentWithItemAndObject (documentId).

Remove the parameter and InViewerSearch is ok.

I can not send parameters loadDocumentWithItemAndObject?
Thank you so much.

Comment: @ClaraAriasDelRey, I did not get that error when I added  viewerApp.loadDocumentWithItemAndObject (documentId, "{3D}"), but yes, only magnifying glass icon is available. However, looking inside Autodesk360App.js, I do not think loadDocumentWithItemAndObject accepts a param like '{3D}' which is the name of the item. If debugging with '{3D}', you will find loadDocumentWithItemAndObject  failed to get the item to be shown, so nothing is displayed. Instead, it requires the guid of the item. After I set the param with a valid guid, it works well to load Viewer and Search again.

Comment: I have modified Autodesk360App.js, to send by parameter the name instead of guid, I have left it to the original state and it already works. Thank you!